# Как сделать разным цвет строк в TextBox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать разным цвет строк в TextBox WPF?

Нужно, чтобы на первой строке текст был красным, на второй - зеленым.

Желательно ответить с примером, т.к. я еще не опытный.

Пример, как нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У `TextBox`'а нет такой функциональности. Вам нужен `RichTextBox`. В `RichTextBox`'е можно выделить произвольный текст и назначить ему цвет

Comment: Как это сделать там?

Comment: А какой функционал TextBox вам нужен? Может вам нужен не он, а ListBox или типа того?

Answer (score 3):

> У TextBox'а нет такой функциональности. Вам нужен RichTextBox. В
>   RichTextBox'е можно выделить произвольный текст и назначить ему цвет

Для начала нам надо получить `TextRange` - фрагмент текста, с которымуже можно работать дальше (устанавливать цвет, в том числе).

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

Здесь мы выделили весь документ и назначили ему красный цвет.

Можно выделять произвольные куски текста. Например через метод `TextPointer.GetPositionAtOffset`, в котором указываете смещение.